# Operate values within a DataFrame of pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following procedures:

1. I have a DataFrame "sales", I have managed to group these data through "keys", and add all the values of "Col2" and "Col3" where the "Cond" == "T". Getting "sum_ans".

   ```
    import pandas as pd 

    sales = pd.DataFrame({"keys" : [1,    1,  1,  1,  3,  3,  3,  3,  3],
                      "Col2" : [2,    3,  5,  7,  4,  5, -8,  1,  7],
                      "Col3" : [-1,   9,-13,  2, -2, -6,  1,  -1, 0],
                      "Cond" : ["T","T","F","F","T","T","F","F","F"]}) 

    print(sales)

    # Step 1
    key = sales.groupby('keys')

    sum_col2 = key.apply(lambda x: x[x['Cond'] == 'T']['Col2'].sum())
    sum_col3 = key.apply(lambda x: x[x['Cond'] == 'T']['Col3'].sum())
    sum_ans = pd.concat([sum_col2, sum_col3], axis = 1)

    # Step 2
    #=IF(ABS(MIN(B1:B4))>MAX(B1:B4),MIN(B1:B4),MAX(B1:B4)) 
    max_col2 = key.apply(lambda x: x[x['Cond'] == 'F']['Col2'].max())
    max_col3 = key.apply(lambda x: x[x['Cond'] == 'F']['Col3'].max())
    max_ans = pd.concat([max_col2, max_col3], axis = 1)enter code here
   ```
2. Now what I'm looking for is that for "Col2" and "Col3", extract the value furthest from zero where the "Cond" == "F". (Note: If you laugh at the case of choosing between -1 and 1, then I take positive value). Getting "maxis_ans" should be something like this:

What I have is the maximum positive, but that's not what I'm looking for. What I am looking for is this:

```
Keys
1  7 -13
3 -8   1
```

3. Once this is obtained, the results of both DataFrames must be superimposed (add), to result in the following DataFrame:

   ```
   keys      
   1     12  -21
   3      1   -7
   ```

I would greatly appreciate that you can help me with feedback, and if there is a more efficient procedure, much better. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can def your own function

```
def yourfuc(y,z):
    x = y[y['Cond']=='F']
    return x.loc[(x[z].abs() == x[z].abs().max()),z].iloc[0]
    
max_col2 = key.apply(lambda x: yourfuc(x,'Col2'))
max_col3 = key.apply(lambda x: yourfuc(x,'Col3'))
max_ans = pd.concat([max_col2, max_col3], axis = 1)
max_ans
      0   1
keys       
1     7 -13
3    -8   1
```

Comment: Thank you very much @BENY, and maybe you could tell me your logical procedure to understand a little better your solution? Please indicate the same result but without defining the function. Thanks.